# is twitter-bootstrap-rails compatible with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Is twitter-bootstrap-rails compatible with rails 4 and ruby 2.0. I was having tons of trouble installing this on my rails app after going through two railscast and the readme on its github page. Sorry I couldn't find a straight forward answer both in the repo's issues and from googling online.

on the repo page it says

```
Twitter Bootstrap for Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline
```

Comment: Not sure about that gem, but [here is a post](http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/1l9ea0/installing_bootstrap_into_an_existing_rails_4_app/) about installing bootstrap-sass-rails into rails 4

Comment: @lightswitch05 Thanks! will check it out later !

Comment: Personally, I prefer to just download bootstrap's `css` and `js` and put it into my `vender\assets` folder. Especially with the bootstrap 3 release, it might be easier to just maintain the version yourself.

Comment: I've gotten it to work with Rails 4 projects.  Is there a specific error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

To get bootstrap in Rail 4.

Add `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to your Gemfile.

and then add  `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";`
  and         `@import "bootstrap";`

to the top of your application.scss file. Don't forget to run bundle install.